# does Cyanogenmod 7.2 Madteam release 16/6 on Vodafone 858 support USB host?

Tags: cyanogenmod, usb, usb-host-mode, huawei-u8160

I've a Huawei u8160 which is running Cyanogenmod 7.2.

I saw in the change log that it has better support for USB mouse and keyboard and it was written beside it COMMON.

Quoted from the Cyanogenmod github [CHANGELOG.mkdn](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_vendor_cyanogen/blob/gingerbread/CHANGELOG.mkdn#changelog-notable-new-features-or-fixes):

> ...
>
> Common: Better support for mouse and usb keyboards - Emilio Lopez, Tanguy Pruvot
>
> ...

So I was wondering if it supports USB host so I can connect it with a USB mouse and keyboard ?

Comment: Can you clarify the title as its misleading and confusing?

Comment: Also, can you include the link to where you saw this change log? (Have an account with Madteam and see no reference to CM 7.2?)

Comment: The change log is in the settings and I mean that the release of Cyanogenmod is released on 16/6/2012 and there was an error in the title I'll fix it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Common: Better support for mouse and usb keyboards` found at the [changelog](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_vendor_cyanogen/blob/gingerbread/CHANGELOG.mkdn#changelog-notable-new-features-or-fixes) refers to all devices supported, meaning that there was an overall improvement on the USB support for mouse and keyboard devices.

But take into account that the words "better support" means that there was an improvement, but it may still be buggy on certain devices under specific situations.

**As a side note:**

To your particular case, you are referring that **you have a Huawei U8160**, but on the changelog, the **support goes for Huawei U8150**. So, it may not be fully supported with or device.

---

### Relevant Links:

The changelog can be found at: [github - CyanogenMod](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_vendor_cyanogen/blob/gingerbread/CHANGELOG.mkdn#changelog-notable-new-features-or-fixes)

CyanogenMod Forums: [CyanogenMod 7.2 Released! (2012-Jun-16)](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/forum-509/announcement-23-cyanogenmod-72-released-2012-jun-16/)

Wikipedia: [List of devices supported by CyanogenMod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_devices_supported_by_CyanogenMod)

Answer (score 1):

You can try because the chipset is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, go for it and try it out and report back here. :)

What the wording '*Common*' means is this, common to all devices regardless of platform. Its a CM thing in documenting the changes made.

If there was a specific device in there it would be highlighted, for example, '*OMAP Common*' refers to those devices that has ARMv7 media processing embedded on the chip or SoC, by Texas Instruments (generally found in high end devices)