# My Huawei u8160(Vodafone 858) supports usb-host although not working?

Tags: cyanogenmod, kernel, usb-host-mode

I have a Huawei u8160 running [Psyke83's Cyanogenmod 7.2 14/8/2012](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1259739) which had a [package](http://goo.im/devs/psyke83/roms/u8160/20120814) with it to apply usb-host mode kernel called [usbhost1-cm-7-20120814-MADTEAM-u8160.zip](http://goo.im/devs/psyke83/roms/u8160/20120814/usbhost1-cm-7-20120814-MADTEAM-u8160.zip).

So I flashed the zip using clockwork mod recovery (from [Rom Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.rommanager)) and was successful although when I started my phone and connected an USB mouse it didn't light(the mouse) and it wasn't working.

I want to ask here,what's wrong?

---

**EDIT #1:**

I downloaded the app [USB host controller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hu.sztupy.android.usbhostcontroller) and when I opened it it told me that "S3C USB Host driver NOT found!"

---

**EDIT #2:**

I've found this [blog](http://logout.hu/bejegyzes/szoke12/vodafone_858_smart_huawei_u8160_usb_host_mod/hsz_1-50.html) (it's in Hungarian so I translated it using Google) talking about exactly my state and it says that I need a Y-Cable to feed the usb peripheral with power, so I'm going to try that and then I'll report here.

---

**USB Y-Cable :**

[image]

Comment: The answers to this previous question sound relevant to what you're trying [does Cyanogenmod 7.2 Madteam release 16/6 on Vodafone 858 support USB host?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24811/does-cyanogenmod-7-2-madteam-release-16-6-on-vodafone-858-support-usb-host)

Comment: @GAThrawn but that doesn't answer anything now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it,

I needed a Y-Cable and I needed to activate the usb host mode by using this command in the terminal emulator :

```
su
insmod /system/lib/modules/ehci-hcd.ko
```

that activates the usb host mode.

and the phone doesn't mount the flash drives so I have to mount it manually :

```
cd /dev/block
ls
```

the terminal emulator should turn out something like uba,uba1 then create a folder in your sdcard called data (or whatever you like) and then type the one ending with 1 (i.e uba1) like this :

```
mount /dev/block/ub*1 /mnt/sdcard/data
```

(*) stands for the changed letter because it always starts with ub and ends in 1 but the third character changes between a,b,c,....

then open any file explorer and do whatever you want with data folder in your sdcard and then just unplug it, no need to unmount safely.

Comment: Thanks! I guess this could also work with the Huawei u8150.. so it means the Y-Cable was for extra power and why did you have to mess around with the terminal.. didn't the usb host controller app work?

Comment: only insmod command was needed (and that needs su command) and the other commands are for mounting the flash drives @Power-Inside